# How to search entire Pandas dataframe for a string and get the name of the column that contains it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, string-matching

I want to find *the name of the column* in a dataframe ("categories") that contains a given string.

```
categories

    Groceries   Electricity Fastfood    Parking 
0   SHOP        ELCOMPANY   MCDONALDS   park
1   MARKET      ELECT       Subway      car
2   market      electr      Restauran   247
```

Say I want to search this entire dataframe for string "MCDO". **The answer should be "Fastfood"**. I tried using str.contains but it doesn't seem to work for dataframes.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can search for the entire string, it makes it easier,

```
(df == 'MCDONALDS').any().idxmax()
```

else use apply,

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith('MCDO').any()).idxmax()
```

Comment: I like the first one a lot - it's short and works perfectly, showing just "Fastfood" instead of "Index(['Fastfood'], dtype='object')" from the earlier attempt lambda attempt.

Comment: What was the first function? You started with a "("

Comment: @christfan868, the best way to understand the code would be by breaking it down. df == 'MCDONALDS' returns a boolean df, (df == 'MCDONALDS').any() returns True along axis 0 if the condition is True for any value (hence the bracket)

Answer (score 2):

You can check with `contains` with `any`

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('MCDO')).any().loc[lambda x : x].index
Index(['Fastfood'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Lol, :-), :D, YW

Comment: Note that: `df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('MCDO')).any().loc[lambda x : x].index.item()` would only return the column name.

Answer (score 2):

Or use:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('MCDO')).replace(False,np.nan).dropna(axis=1,how='all').columns.item())
```

Output:

```
Fastfood
```

Answer (score 2):

One can also use `for` loop for this:

```
def strfinder(df, mystr):
    for col in df:
        for item in df[col]:
            if mystr in item:
                return col

print(strfinder(df, 'MCDO'))
```

To get all columns that may have the string, e.g. in modified dataframe below:

```
    Groceries   Electricity  Fastfood    Parking 
0   SHOP        ELCOMPANY   MCDONALDS   park
1   MARKET      MCDON       Subway      car
2   market      electr      Restauran   247
```

one can use "list comprehension":

```
mystr = 'MCDO'
outlist = [ col 
            for col in df 
            for item in df[col]
            if mystr in item    ]
print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
['Electricity', 'Fastfood']
```

Comment: Thank you, looks quite nice although people tend to say using for loops with Pandas is always wrong. But if it works, it works.

Comment: They are easy to understand and fast enough for most purposes. However, if your data is large, more optimized approaches should be used.